# In laravel, how to create multiple accounts for testing purposes, without having many emails?

Tags: laravel

How to create multiple accounts on a site I'm developing?

If I could, I'd disable email requirement and validation completely, I just don't know what to edit for this.

This is a local site, working on my computer.

Comment: I think email verification is disabled by default. Have you added the MustVerifyEmail contract? Remove it. ([https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification)). Or did i just not understand your question?

Comment: Oh, that's perfect then! I haven't tried to create an account yet actually. Question closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use factories to generate dummy Users.

Open `database/factories/UserFactory.php` and complete it with columns matching the columns in your `users` table.

For example:

```php
$factory->define(App\User::class, function(Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'first_name'        => $faker->firstName,
        'last_name'         => $faker->lastName,
        'email'             => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password'          => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token'    => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

To see the list of possible formatters, see https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#formatters, this is what Laravel is using.

Then create a seed: `php artisan make:seed UsersTableSeeder`

Then enable (uncomment) this seed in `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`:

```php
public function run()
{
    $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
}
```

Inside `UsersTableSeeder.php`, paste in the following:

```php
public function run()
{
    $users = factory(App\User::class, 15)->make()->toArray();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        App\User::create($user);
    }
}
```

Change the number `15` to the number of dummy Users you want to fake.

Then run `php artisan db:seed` to insert them to the database. Voila!

To read more about factories, see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database-testing#writing-factories

Comment: Thank you! Been looking for this as well. One question: would I be able to run a factory on production?

Comment: Yes you can, think you can use the `--force` tag to avoid the possible 'Are you sure?' questions. Haven't done it myself but won't break anything, just seed the database with new info.

Comment: Unless of course your user has foreign constraints and depends on other tables or vice versa. And if you don't have unique values clashing, or you insert ID values that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a seeder for the Users table 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/seeding
.And then use Faker to generate emails 
https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker